# LINQ count in group from join

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ statement I am trying to get right, so maybe going about this all wrong. My objective is to query a table and join in another table to get counts.

**Places**
ID, Display

**ProfilePlaces**
ID, PlaceID, Talk, Hear

Basically `Places` have `ProfilePlaces` in a one to many relationship. I want to get the number `SUM` of `ProfilePlaces` that have `Talk`and `Hear`. `Talk`and `Hear` are `bit` fields.

The following gives me a unique list of `Places`, so I need to add in the `Talk`and `Hear` counts.

```
var counts = from p in db.Places
             join pp in db.ProfilePlaces on p.ID equals pp.PlaceID
             group new { Place = p } by p.Display;
```

I thought something like this, but not having any luck

```
var counts = from p in db.Places
             join pp in db.ProfilePlaces on p.ID equals pp.PlaceID
             group new { Place = p, 
                         Talk = pp.Count(t => t.Talk == true),
                         Hear = pp.Count(t => t.Hear == true) 
                       } by p.Display;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hear == Meet? is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to do a GROUP JOIN to get the counts for each `Place`.

```
var counts2 = from p in places
              join pp in profilePlaces on p.ID equals pp.PlaceID into g
              select new
              {
                   Place = p,
                   CountMeet = g.Count(a => a.Meet),
                   CountTalk = g.Count(a => a.Talk)
              };
```

Here's the documentation on the different joins from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: I believe this is the solution. How would you add a `WHERE` condition to this query?

Comment: I think where should come before the select. What are you trying to filter on?

Comment: I actually have another collection of `int`'s that I check for existance in. `colInts.Contains(pp.ID)`

Comment: If colInts is just a local variable I think you can just put it as a where clause between the join and select or you can first limit the pp records by colInts in a separate statement and then group join on the result. I'd update my answer but it's tough from my phone =]

Comment: You are correct, I needed to filter that out first, then move to the counts.